# Why do my images not work on Github pages?

Tags: javascript, css, html, github-pages

Frodo is supposed to get hit by a rock every time you enter a wrong letter, but it doesn't work...

Website link:
https://tenthyoung.github.io/LordOfTheRings-Hangman/

GitHub repo link: https://github.com/tenthyoung/LordOfTheRings-Hangman

Comment: I won ^.^ They destroy the ring.

Comment: LOLOL nice man xD

Answer (score 4):

Your URL says `./assets/images/Frodo.PNG` but you have to spell PNG lowercase.
So the correct url would be: `./assets/images/Frodo.png`

You can test this out by going to the URL manually, this is your original: [Your original image](https://tenthyoung.github.io/LordOfTheRings-Hangman/assets/images/Frodo.PNG) and now change .PNG to .png you see the image: [working image](https://tenthyoung.github.io/LordOfTheRings-Hangman/assets/images/Frodo.png)

Comment: sweet! thanks so much man. that made the frodo work for the first image, but now when i guess a wrong letter, it still doesn't show frodo getting hit by a rock. do you have any advice on this, mate? o_o

Comment: You load in a different URL by changing the class. But you need to give it a bit more time I think. Set it to change the class to .hit-frodo and leave it there for about 10 seconds. Maybe even leave it there and don't change the class again and see if the image even loads.

Comment: I tested it, as far as I can see the image of hitting Frodo works. What you need to do is change the class, but wait a little longer before removing it again. Also don't remove the class but change it to .regular-frodo which sets the content:url back to the original content. Because when you delete the class .hit-frodo the original image is not loaded again

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you have 'class' written at the end of the image tag, that won't work